# Giving a Tame Budgie to a New Owner

Tags: birds, budgerigar

How would a tame budgie react when given to another home? Would he get sick because he is away from his previous owner?

Comment: is the new owner prepared to get a new pet,you are responsible for the pets life and you need to make sure it gets the care it needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had it in two cases where I raised birds by hand, an Indian myna, and a cockatiel. I went away from them for work. They both stopped eating in my absence and starved themselves to death.

With that said, I've had many more instances where we re-homed birds to us, and they were fine. They adapted quite quickly to their new environments. But they were not as tame as a hand-reared bird.

It is near impossible to predict how the birds will respond to their new environment and owners. I would suggest getting the bird used to the new person who would be taking care of them. Also, be available to take the bird back if they don't adjust.

Wishing you the best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I can add my particular experience with budgies. My family have kept a few budgies (alone or in pairs, kept in a cage with the door open during the day, in a room where the door is kept closed) over the years and we’ve also looked after each other’s pets while on holiday. We’ve looked after them in our homes, so temporary change of both owner and environment, and sometimes there was even a resident budgie in the holiday home.

I’ve not had any problems with them stopping eating, and my sister's budgie had no problem snuggling with me. The one thing I noticed is that they don’t like flying and landing in unfamiliar rooms - they’ll land on furniture in their own homes but prefer people or their cages in rooms they don’t know. I’d be more wary of obesity than starvation.